# Smooth scrolling in Windows 10 programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, thinkpad

On Chrome and Atom, when I scroll using my trackpad, the page scrolls proportionally to how much I move my fingers.

On programs such as Windows Explorer and Notepad++, when I scroll, the page doesn't move until a certain threshold. Then, it jumps X lines, which I've set in the settings. This makes it difficult to visually track which line is which after scrolling.

Is there a way to make all programs scroll smoothly like Chrome?

I've tried changing the settings so it scrolls 1 line at a time, but then Chrome scrolls too slowly.

I'm using Windows 10 Insider Preview on a Thinkpad T470.

Comment: This is a question on the same topic [link](https://superuser.com/questions/956381/no-smooth-scrolling-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:
https://www.smoothscroll.net/win/
(just a user, not promotion)

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have an Elantech touchpad? If so, you might resolve various scrolling issues with the following steps:

1. Open regedit.exe using run
2. Go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`
3. Change `ScrollControl_Mode` from `0` to `1`

(Via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64345483/125938)